# Speeding up getting values from a large number of text boxes and storing into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm writing a webpage which has a huge list of text boxes which are populated server side. 
On page load, I need to get all the values from the text boxes and store them in an array. Currently I'm doing this like so:

List of textboxes:

```
<input name="hdnID" type="hidden">256<input>
<input name="hdnCode" type="hidden">XXXXX<input>
<input name="hdnName" type="hidden">Name 1<input>
<input name="hdnID" type="hidden">257<input>
<input name="hdnCode" type="hidden">XXXXY<input>
<input name="hdnName" type="hidden">Name 2<input>
...
```

JavaScript/Jquery:

```
  var count = $('[name=hdnCode]').length;
  var arrItems = new Array();

  for (i=0; i < count; i++)
  {
      var joItem = {
              "itemID"       : $('[name=hdnID]')[i].value,
              "itemCode"     : $('[name=hdnCode]')[i].value,
              "itemName"     : $('[name=hdnName]')[i].value
          };

    arrItems[i] = joItem;
  }
```

Currently there is 1045 items on my page which results in 3135 text boxes! On IE8 I am getting a popup that says "Stop Running this script? A script on the page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly..". Can anybody think of a way that I can speed this up or make it more efficient so that IE 8 can handle it ok?

Comment: Have you thought of introducing a UI control like [pagination](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Pagination). Surely you don't need 1k items on a single page? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute selectors are generally not that efficient, so try some other way of selecting the inputs you want (e.g. all inputs under a particular parent).

Also you are not caching the result of the selection so it has to do it over and over again.

i.e.

```
 var hdnIDs =  $('[name=hdnID]');
 var hdnCodes = $('[name=hdnCode]');
 var hdnNames = $('[name=hdnName]');
 var count = hdnCodes.length; 
 for (i=0; i < count; i++)
  {
      var joItem = {
              "itemID"       : hdnIDs[i].value,
              "itemCode"     : hdnCodes[i].value,
              "itemName"     : hdnNames[i].value
      };

      arrItems[i] = joItem;
  }
```

Should be more efficient.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I have implemented the caching like you have suggested and it sped the system up a considerable amount! Unfortunately It was not enough to get rid of the annoying IE popup error so I am now exploring other methods and getting rid of the textboxes all together. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try caching the value arrays and optimizing your for loop:

```
var count = $('[name=hdnCode]').length,
    allID = $('[name=hdnID]'),
    allCode = $('[name=hdnCode]'),
    allName = $('[name=hdnName]'),
    arrItems = new Array();

for ( var i = count; i--; ) {

    var joItem = {
        "itemID"       : allID[i].value,
        "itemCode"     : allCode[i].value,
        "itemName"     : allName[i].value
    };

    arrItems[i] = joItem;
}
```

From http://www.phpied.com/extreme-javascript-optimization/:

> This loop will execute 50% faster because on every
>   iteration it simply subtracts a value from i, and since that value is
>   not "falsy," in other words it isn't 0, then the loop goes on. The
>   moment the value hits 0, the loop stops.

Comment: Be careful of such claims, javascript for loops are becoming very highly optimised. If a simple decrementing counter is required, use a while loop. It probably won't be any faster, but is more suited to the job.

Comment: As you can see from the tests [here](http://jsperf.com/for-and-while-loops-20130), the difference between different loop styles is very minor (nothing like 50%) and varies between browsers. Just use whatever is most appropriate for the circumstance, keep it simple and clear for maintainers and optimise only if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

use data attribute

```
<input name="hdnID" type="hidden" data-inpname="itemID">256<input>
<input name="hdnCode" type="hidden" data-inpname="itemCode">XXXXX<input>
```

try this

```
var arrItems ={};
$('input').each(function(i,v){
    var $this=$(this), 
        name=$this.data('inpname');
        value=$this.val(); 

    arrItems.name=value;
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, I have never seen the data attribute before!
Unfortunately I can't use HTML5 because this is internal software for a company still using old versions of IE - eugh :(

Answer (score 0):

Mark's answer is efficient. But if that will also fail if you are array is very huge.But i have an solution for that.  Do think of having separate pages and try to use more web technologies like localstorage, ajax, etc.,

Try this code

```
var hdnIDs =  $('[name=hdnID]');
var hdnCodes = $('[name=hdnCode]');
var hdnNames = $('[name=hdnName]');
var hdnIDsDup = hdnIDs.concat();
var hdnCodesDup = hdnCodes.concat();
var hdnNamesDup = hdnNames.concat();


function process(hdnIDs,hdnCodes,hdnNames){
        var joItem = {
              "itemID"       : hdnIDs.value,
              "itemCode"     : hdnCodes.value,
              "itemName"     : hdnNames.value
      };
      arrItems[i] = joItem;
   }


 setTimeout(function(){

    var start = +new Date();

    do {
         process.call(context, hdnIDsDup.shift(),hdnCodesDup.shift(),hdnNamesDup.shift());
    } while (hdnCodesDup.length > 0 && (+new Date() - start < 50));

    if (hdnCodesDup.length > 0){
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 25);
    } else {
        callback(array);
    }
}, 25);
```

The do while loop present inside the timeout function will execute for milliseconds and the second timeout makes sure to loop again if there are anymore elements present inside the array we are processing.

You can find more details about this method in the following link.
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/05/what-determines-that-a-script-is-long-running/
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/08/11/timed-array-processing-in-javascript/

Comment: Could you explain what you're timeout function is doing?

Comment: @user1636130: I have updated my answer and have given you links for reference.